# Connecting two separate sockets through serversocket

Tags: java, sockets

I'm developing a chat application in Java that enables client to connect to a predefined port and when two clients are connected the server should connect those two sockets and data should be exchanged between them.

I know to create a `ServerSocket` and `Socket` that will connect and establish a communication between them through a separate port and a server socket. But, how can I connect those two connected clients?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a chat application then Chat server will not connect client socket in order to communicate.

You can try following approach:

1. On server side Use a HashTable to store connected clients.
2. When you receive a message from client, include a an id of CLient to whom message is to be sent and simply pass on the message to other client.
3. There will be separate threads running for these clients, so you need to have a policy to control the load on server.

Answer (score 0):

This questions sounds like a homework assignment.
If you would like to see a great contemporary demo of a chat system you may learn from Play's  [WebSocket chat](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Samples) sample application.